# Cosine and sine rule on a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

$\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with legs $AC=BC=b$ and angle $\measuredangle ACB=\gamma$. Let $CD$ and $BM$ be altitudes that intersect at $H$. Find $MD$.

[image]

I have been struggling with this problem for an hour now. I really don't know how to start. I was thinking about using cosine or sine rule, but it seems useless at the end. For example
$$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2\cdot AC\cdot BC\cdot \cos\gamma=2b^2-2b^2\cos\gamma$$

Comment: the angle MBA is known, you can get the point M as the intersection of straight lines whose angular coefficients you know. at that point you just need to make the distance between two points of the plane between D and M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that quadrilateral MDBC is inscribed. Then, show that $\angle MAD=\angle AMD$ so $\triangle ADM$ is isosceles with $MD=AD$. Finally, you have to express $AD$ in terms of $b$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to show $\angle MAD=\angle AMD$?

Comment: @nicoledobreva $\angle AMD=180^{\circ}-\angle CMD$. Also, your drawing has $\angle ACD=\gamma$ and not $\angle ACB$. That's a mistake, I guess?

Comment: I am trying to find $AB$ using the cosine rule on triangle ABC. I got that $AB=\sqrt{2b^2(1-\cos\gamma)}$. The possible answers are $b\cos\gamma;b\sin\gamma,b\sin\dfrac{\gamma}{2}$ and $b$. Well, using the fact that $MD=AB=\dfrac{1}{2}AB$ we cannot get such answer.

Comment: I meant $MD=AD=..$

Comment: @nicoledobreva There's no contradiction because you haven't simplified this: $2(1-\cos\gamma)=\sin^2(\gamma/2)$. Then take roots. But you can find $AD$ directly from $\triangle ACD$ using the definition of sine. There's really no need to use law of cosines.

Comment: Yes, $\angle ACB=\gamma$

Comment: I found something easier. Triangle $ABM$ is a right triangle and $MD$ is the median to the hypotenuse, so $MD=AD=BD=\dfrac12 AB$. No need of inscribed quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

$$\therefore MD = AD = b\sin \gamma$$

Comment: A really nice diagram. How did you do it?

Comment: @nicoledobreva On [Geogebra website](https://www.geogebra.org/classic?lang=en) and exported image to MS Paint.

Comment: I don't see this option for exporting. I have GeoGebra file, PNG image, SVG image, PDF document, 3D Print. Which one do you choose?

Comment: Oh, I see. And then you exported in MS Paint? Can I ask why?

Comment: @nicoledobreva To crop the image so it appears big here. You can upvote if you found this answer useful.

Comment: I can't really crop my image to look big here. [+1] Thank you!

Comment: Alright. Thank you!